# Typescript types for Solid-js components

Tags: typescript, jsx, solid-js

How do I convert the [first example](https://github.com/ryansolid/solid#the-gist) from the Solid-JS documentation to be valid typescript?

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web"

const HelloMessage = props => <div>Hello {props.name}</div>

render(() => <HelloMessage name="Taylor" />, document.getElementById("hello-example"))
```

I'm getting an error about `props` having no type hint, specifically `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

With react I would use `React.FC`, but I can't find the equivalent with Solid-JS.

Comment: Relevant docs: https://www.solidjs.com/guides/typescript#component-types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution, is using the `Component` generic:

```
import {render} from 'solid-js/web'
import {Component} from 'solid-js'

const HelloMessage: Component<{name: string}> = (props) => <div>Hello {props.name}</div>

render(() => <HelloMessage name="Taylor" />, document.getElementById("hello-example"))
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative could be the following (without having to import type `Component`):

[» Demo](https://playground.solidjs.com/#NobwRAlgJmBcYEcBOAPAFgQwEwBcDOKEAxgAwDuAZgF4CsWAtgHYCmA7AK5gA0YjG9zOGHoYIjbmBwBPAA6D4+FBLwB7dkiLzI9GSqQ4ABCCTNGUZkgC+BikhX0DAclUAbaAFoAVngD0ZZgBGjgA6jKEU7IxEOBAqjAYAEswuLioAssx4eBgA5swAFDJ2MniwRqEGBnwCZXg4SGI5oZYAlOXxBiY46vH5FZUGADxQEABuAHz9A4nJqUZFKiUAdNXMllNDPiMT-S3NoaEmZhb5+W0AvONDSSnpmdl5VfzM58FgACoYUqlIbwY+4y4BigKiI7AEjBwSzyOAAoi5mBCcAAhKQASSg+UcGBkMkcLRaYEsAF0gA)

```
import {render} from 'solid-js/web'

function HelloMessage(props: {
  name: string
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello {props.name}
    </div>
  )
}

render(() => <HelloMessage name="Taylor" />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Or if you prefer:

```
const HelloMessage = (props: { name: string }) =>
  <div>Hello {props.name}</div>
```

BTW: In your question you are using `Hello {props.name}` which is fine as `props` is a reactive object and the expression `props.name` is also reactive ... in your answer you are using `Hello {name}` instead, which will never update, as `name` is just a string which is by nature constant and therefore none-reactive.

Comment: Thanks for the note about `props.name`, I edited the original answer to fix this issue

Comment: IntelliJ then does not support auto completion